# Does Yongnuo YN50 provide Auto Focus with Nikon D5600?

Tags: yongnuo, prime, lens-recommendation, nikon-d5600

I want to buy **Yongnuo YN50** prime lens for my Nikon D5600 camera. I have got 2 main questions regarding it:

1. I am not to find information if it provides AF with Nikon D5600 body (*for example, Nikon F/1.8D doesn't provide AF since it doesn't have an inbuilt motor inside*).
2. While searching on Amazon.de, I found two options to buy this lens ***with different prices***. Both the links are Prime, by Yongnuo, sold by the same company, for Nikon; so, I am little confused if Yongnuo provides two options for Nikon, or is there any other difference between the lenses on the following links:

   - https://www.amazon.de/Yongnuo-Nikon-Objektiv-Kameras-Schwarz/dp/B01E38TZDC/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1516441475&sr=8-6&keywords=50mm%2Blens%2Byongnuo&th=1
   - https://www.amazon.de/YN50mm-F1-8-DSLR-Kamera-Autofokus-WINGONEER/dp/B01G2WQJ54/ref=pd_sbs_421_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=729G2JPYAP49D9GTW1EK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this: https://nikonrumors.com/2017/06/24/yongnuo-yn-50mm-f1-8-lens-review-for-nikon-f-mount.aspx/, yes - it seems to be a copy of the Nikon 50mm F1.8 G.

It looks like the two links refer to the same lens, but one comes with a flash diffuser while the other doesn't. (Apologies if I misunderstood the links - my schoolboy German is bad enough that I thought "auf Lager" meant "on the lager"...).

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any hard information on the Yongnuo site, but from this Amazon ad - [YONGNUO YN EF 50mm f/1.8 AF Lens YN50 Aperture Auto Focus for Nikon Cameras as AF-S 50mm 1.8G](https://www.amazon.co.uk/YONGNUO-Aperture-Cameras-EACHSHOT-Cleaning/dp/B01HEZK95Y) it claims to be AF-S which would work on a motorless camera such as the D5600.

The Q/A & reviews below cover D3xxx & D5xxx users, who mostly would seem to be satisfied with their purchase.
I noticed one complaint about the motor volume too [for video] - which would also indicate it does have one.

It would be surprising if they didn't make this with a built-in motor, as I'm certain their target market is the low-mid range user who wouldn't own a camera with its own focus motor.